# Election page comment anchors don't work

Tags: bug, election

It's pretty straightforward. You get a comment reply on the election page, it shows up on your inbox, and you click it... and you only get to the top of the election page. Nothing more.

Even worse. You *are* on the election page, you get a new comment reply, you click it on the inbox, and nothing happens at all, because there are no anchors.

(This is also noticeable from the fact the timestamp does not have a clickable link.)

Can we please fix that?

Comment: Mildly frustrating and wish comments are linkable like normal comments.

Comment: As I mentioned in the chat, comments which do not need to be "expanded" to be seen seem to be working properly. This may be useful to know for the purposes of fixing the bug.

PS: Another potential bug is the fact that trying to see the elections page from the mobile app from my cell phone returns "Loading the question failed."

Comment: Just to clarify: The mobile bug I mentioned happens when I try to access the election's page by clicking on a reply on the inbox.

Comment: Noticed this as well. Perhaps, the comments box will open up _after_ the elections are done. It seems all other election pages have comment boxes.

Comment: Yeah, this has been an issue for... ages. Trivia: it's the reason why we don't have voting & flagging on election comments - there was no way to link to them from the moderator flag dashboard!

Comment: @Shog9: I thought that the lack of votes was due to the fact that "I support this candidate" became a sort of preliminary voting system, and it was something to be avoided.

Comment: Naw, that only became a problem when a handful of people figured out that we hadn't *really* disabled voting and were voting for comments they liked via script while everyone else looked on.

Comment: @Shog: I'm confused. Does that mean that at some point you just stopped displaying the score, but voted comments still show up if they have a high score?

Comment: We never stopped displaying the score... Originally we just hid the voting controls. Then, later, we actually disabled the ability to vote. With no one able to vote, comments could no longer have a score to display. But... If you go back and look at comments on [old election posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/1), they do have scores and those scores do matter.

Comment: @Shog: Yeah, I know that, I went to check old elections to make sure I wasn't imagining a time where comments worked "as usual" even on election page... :P

Comment: @Shog9 so...SE is not planning to fix it, right?

Comment: Eventually, I hope to. Probably not tomorrow.

Comment: Permalinks to comments on the nomination posts are now available. Relevant Meta SE post: [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979). The inbox notifications also go to the relevant comment now upon clicking them.